# Where can I find the code for my Ford Figo music player

Tags: ford, audio

In changing cars, I have moved my old Ford Figo music player to the new car. But I have forgotten the codes for it. How can I find this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Which codes are you refering to? If you can provide a model number for the media player that may help people. Also, you may just need to go to a dealer (or possibly contact a dealer) to get that information. If not a dealer, then whoever makes the unit will surely have all that information.

Answer (score 1):

Typically these codes are in the owner's manual. Check the documentation that came with the car.

I have also seen posts that the code is also on the side of the glove box. Here is a video how to find it - [How to Fix Ford Music System Key Code Issue in Ford Figo / Ford Fiesta Classic](https://youtu.be/5PywllrT_dQ).